# AngularFire Authentication with Route Limiting

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, firebase, angularfire

I'm currently working on my first Angular application. Each hurdle I get over is really helping me with my understanding of how everything in Angular comes together but also programming in general.

Right now, I am experimenting with AngularFire and Firebase as the back end to the application. Further down the line, I will store other data in Firebase, but right now I am focused on getting the User Authentication part down.

Currently, the application is comprised of an `index.html` page, which loads the navigation HTML elements as a header, and then loads partials within an `ng-view` element. This keeps the navigation constant and the pages dynamic (much of the content is generated via Angular from various JSON objects). It also includes a `login.html` that is entirely separate and does not include the navigational elements from the main application, but does use the same controllers and modules as the rest of the application. I've managed to cobble together a working login, which interfaces successfully with Firebase. This can verify existing e-mail/password combinations or register new users. What I really want is for a successful login to redirect to `index.html`, and if someone tries to access `index.html` or any of the partials without having signed in, to be redirected to the `login.html`. I'm not entirely sure how to approach this, though I believe it will have something to do with the router. I'd also like to keep the authentication information attached to a persistent user object so it can be used in controlling the visibility and functionality of navigation options later on.

The Angular code that I am using:

`var profileApp = angular.module('profileApp', ['ngRoute', 'firebase']);`

```
  profileApp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$firebaseAuth', function($scope, $rootScope, $firebaseAuth) {
    var ref = new Firebase('https://FIREBASEURL.firebaseio.com/');
    $rootScope.auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    $scope.signIn = function () {
        $rootScope.auth.$login('password', {
            email: $scope.email,
            password: $scope.password
        }).then(function(user) {
            $rootScope.alert.message = '';
        }, function(error) {
            if (error = 'INVALID_EMAIL') {
                console.log('email invalid or not signed up — trying to sign you up!');
                 $scope.signUp();
                } else if (error = 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
                console.log('wrong password!');
                } else {
                console.log(error);
                }   
        });
    }

    $scope.signUp = function() {
        $rootScope.auth.$createUser($scope.email, $scope.password, function(error, user) {
            if (!error) {
                $rootScope.alert.message = '';
            } else {
                $rootScope.alert.class = 'danger';
                $rootScope.alert.message = 'The username and password combination you entered is invalid.';
            }
        });
    }
  }
  ]);

profileApp.controller('AlertCtrl', [
    '$scope', '$rootScope', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.alert = {};
    }
]);

profileApp.controller('HistoryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('patient.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.historyItems = data;
    });
  });

profileApp.controller('FaceCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('patient.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.faceItems = data;
    });
  });     
profileApp.controller('PhysicalCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('patient.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.physicalItems = data;
    });
  });
profileApp.controller('MenuCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('profile.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.profileItems = data;
    });
  });
profileApp.controller('ContentCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('content.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.contentItems = data;
    });
  });
profileApp.controller('OrdersCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('patient.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.ordersItems = data;
    });
  });
profileApp.controller('MedAdminCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('patient.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.medadminItems = data;
    });
  });
profileApp.controller('LabsCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('patient.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.labItems = data;
    });
  });
profileApp.controller('VitalsCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('patient.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.vitalItems = data;
    });
  });
profileApp.controller('AssessmentCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('patient.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.asessmentItems = data;
    });
  });
profileApp.controller('IoCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('patient.json').success(function(data) {
      $scope.ioItems = data;
    });
  });

profileApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    __insp.push(["virtualPage"]);
    $routeProvider
    // Home
    .when("/", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/face.html", 
                    controller: "FaceCtrl"
            })
    .when("/face", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/face.html", 
                    controller: "FaceCtrl"
                })
    // Pages
    .when("/medicalHistory", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/medicalhistory.html", 
                    controller: "HistoryCtrl"
                })
    .when("/physicalExam", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/physicalexam.html", 
                    controller: "PhysicalCtrl"
                })
    .when("/orders", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/orders.html", 
                    controller: "OrdersCtrl"
                })
    .when("/medAdmin", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/medadmin.html", 
                    controller: "MedAdminCtrl"
                })
    .when("/labs", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/labs.html", 
                    controller: "LabsCtrl"
                })
    .when("/vitals", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/vitals.html", 
                    controller: "VitalsCtrl"
                })
    .when("/assessment", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/assessment.html", 
                    controller: "AssessmentCtrl"
                })
    .when("/io", {
                    templateUrl: "partials/io.html", 
                    controller: "IoCtrl"
                })
    //.when("/contact", {templateUrl: "partials/contact.html", controller: "PageCtrl"})
    // else 404
    .otherwise("/404", {templateUrl: "partials/404.html", controller: "PageCtrl"});
}]);
```

Comment: The AngularFire guide has a pretty decent section on securing routes: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide.html#section-angular-authentication

Comment: And full implementations exist in [angularFire-seed](https://github.com/firebase/angularFire-seed) and [generator-angularfire](https://github.com/firebase/generator-angularfire/)

Answer (score 0):

Here!, Iv changed the code.... Check this out and let me know if this solves the problem!

To Sign In and Sign Up:

```
profileApp.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$firebase',
function($scope, $location, $firebase) {

    $scope.message = "";
    var username = "";
    var password = "";

    var ref = new Firebase("https://FIREBASEURL.firebaseio.com/");
    $scope.signIn = function() {

        username = $scope.username;
        password = $scope.password;

        ref.authWithPassword({
            email: username,
            password: password
        }, function(error, authData) {
            if (error) {
                switch (error.code) {
                    case "INVALID_EMAIL":
                        alert("The specified user account email is invalid.");
                        break;
                    case "INVALID_PASSWORD":
                        alert("The specified user account password is incorrect.");
                        break;
                    case "INVALID_USER":
                        alert("The specified user account does not exist.");
                        break;
                    default:
                        alert("Error logging user in:", error)
                }
                $scope.message = "Wrong Username/Password;";
            } else {
                $location.path("/home");
            }
        }, {
            remember: "sessionOnly"
        });
    };
};

$scope.signUp = function () {
    $rootScope.auth.$createUser($scope.email, $scope.password, function (error, user) {
        if (!error) {
            $rootScope.alert.message = '';
        } else {
            $rootScope.alert.class = 'danger';
            $rootScope.alert.message = 'The username and password combination you entered is invalid.';
        }
    });
};
]);
```

To Sign Out:

```
profileApp.controller('home', ['$scope', '$location', '$firebase',
function($scope, $location, $firebase) {

    function authDataCallback(authData) {
        if (authData) {
            alert("Logged in...");
        } else {
            $location.path("/login");
            alert("Log in to access this page");
        }
    };

    var ref = new Firebase("https://FIREBASEURL.firebaseio.com/");
    ref.onAuth(authDataCallback);
    $scope.logoutUser = function() {
        ref.unauth();
        $location.path("/login");
    };
    //        Authentication Code
```

One more thing! You click the submit button and you will not be navigated to another desired view on correct Username/Password. Here what you will do:

1- After clicking submit button wait for 5-10 seconds.
2- After that click the submit button again. Try this out for now.

Cheers!

Comment: Going to try this over the weekend if I have time. Thanks!

Comment: I have a hunch this is going to work eventually, but I'm now getting an "undefined is not a function" error on  the
`$rootScope.auth.$login('password', {`

Comment: Iv changed the structure, im posting another answer for this which is working fine for me!